# How do I communicate to NodeMCU module through python?

Tags: python, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

Basically I want to be able to send instructions for a bot over WiFi using the nodeMCU module, but I cant find any detailed functions list that can help me.

I've already tried setting up a server on the NodeMCU, and then a html webpage can then be created on my laptop with buttons for instructions from [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0y9PQ7KMNjPS1M0ZFZrTGFuUm8/view) and it works, but when I try to to the same on python, (send GET requests through python) I get this error on trying to do more than one request:

> ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionAbortedError(10053, 'An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine', None, 10053, None))

Also I think the converse would be better suited for my case, a server on the laptop and client as the module, but I don't know where to start.

I coded the on the module using arduino IDE and on my laptop I'm using spyder. For sending requests and stuff I'm using the requests package.

Answer (score 0):

You can create HTTP endpoints in nodeMCU and call them from your python script.
For this to work, both the nodeMCU and the machine running the python script has to be in the same network. and the IP address of the nodeMCU should be correctly added in the python script.

If you wanted to use your laptop as the server, I would suggest going with an MQTT broker such as mosquito, and communicate between the nodeMCU and the python script using the MQTT protocol.

Comment: I actually found a way by using TCP , made a server on the node mcu and used socket on python

Comment: @Yuktee Can you please share the solution you found?